# Event handler for after form is refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a custom call that opens specific form, where I have some default buttons, so after i call form, I override some actions for this buttons. One of the default buttons is also Save which refreshes form so all overrides get lost when I click it. Is it possible to have an event handler that is called on form refresh so the buttons will be overriden every time?

Comment: I suggest you improve your question by demonstrating the issue with a code snippet that has only the __minimum amount of code required__ to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

For example you can prevent the default behaviour of the click of the button

```
$(button_selector).click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
    //Then execute the behaviour you want execute
});
```